# Connect to external HTTPS Elasticsearch with Java Client

Tags: java, ssl, elasticsearch, https

Since I'd want use the Elasticsearch' Java API, I'm trying to connect to external Elasticsearch's REST Server by using the Java TransportClient, the URL I have to call looks like:

```
https://ssl-secure-host/their-index/their-type/_search
```

Obviously I first trusted the certification provided by **ssl-secure-host** by using the keytool and generated the **keystore.jks**.

I don't have any other information about the elasticsearch's index, nodes, etc, I have only the URL above.

This is the TransportClient I'm writting in order to establish a connection:

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
    .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
    .put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false)
    .put("shield.user", "user:password")
    .put("shield.ssl.truststore.path", "/Users/me/path/cert/keystore.jks")
    .put("shield.ssl.truststore.password", "changeit")
    .put("shield.transport.ssl", true);

TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings)
    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("ssl-secure-host", ?????));
```

Could it be possible to establish a connection in any other way or I have to ask to my provider more information about the **host**, **port**, etc?

Or, Do I have to resign myself to do this by implementing a simple REST client to query the Elasticsearch's index other people provide me?

Could it be possible that an Apache HTTP Server exists in the front of elasticsearch nodes?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JEST library. It s an HTTP client for ElasticSearch. So you can use it instead the transport client provided by Elasticsearch

check this link:
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest